# MySQL - Impossible to use REFERENCES on mysql 5.7 (but was working on 5.0)

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to add foreign keys to tables in a database. Let's consider the following minimal example:

```
CREATE DATABASE db_foo;
USE db_foo;
CREATE TABLE a(b VARCHAR(3) PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE c(d VARCHAR(3), KEY c_ix (d));
ALTER TABLE c ADD CONSTRAINT fk_c_a FOREIGN KEY (d) REFERENCES a(b);
```

The code given above works perfectly on a MySQL server with version 5.0.95, but is giving me the following error when I am running it on another server that runs MySQL version 5.7.12:

```
ERROR 1142 (42000): REFERENCES command denied to user 'toto'@'xxx.xxx.xx.xx' for table 'a'
```

So my first guess was to check if I had the same privileges on both server. This is the output of `SHOW GRANTS;`:

**On the server with MySQL 5.0.95:**

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for toto@%                                                                                                                                                                            |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'toto'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*********'                                                                                          |
| GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, EXECUTE, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE ON `db\_%`.* TO 'toto'@'%'  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**On the server with MySQL 5.7.12:**

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for toto@%                                                                                                                                                                                            |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'toto'@'%'                                                                                                                                                                             |
| GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, EXECUTE, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, EVENT, TRIGGER ON `db\_%`.* TO 'toto'@'%' |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I have no idea why it would work in a case and not in the other, given the fact that it seems that I have the same privileges in both cases. Any suggestion?

Comment: In second case you don't have password, try adding password then reply me..

Comment: Hi, in both case I use the same login procedure, with password: `mysql -h <host> -u'toto' -p<password>`. No idea why it does not appear in the `show grants;` output though.

Comment: If you are missing the references privilege, why not just grant it? The error message clearly states what is wrong here. The reason you didn't need it in 5.0 is that this privilege was introduced in MySQL 5.7.6. There are 5027373 other details that work differently in 5.7 than in 5.0. Just wait until you use your first old `group by`-statement. So just listen to the error messages and adjust your database accordingly. You will not be able to update your 11 years old database completely without changes.

Comment: It was indeed a matter of MySQL 5.7 being more verbose than 5.0... I didn't to bothr the DB admins at my work but just adding the `REFERENCES` privilege solved the issue.

Comment: If anybody wants to answer the question I can accept it and close the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In MySQL 5.0/5.1/5.4,  `REFERENCES` grant wasn't yet implemented.

First time I saw this was in MySQL 5.5, but it still wasn't working correctly. However, it is now working properly and from that moment you need grant `REFERENCES` privileges to your user account.

See the MySQL 5.5 documentation: [Table 13.3 - Permissible Privileges for GRANT and REVOKE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html)

> REFERENCES Enable foreign key creation. Levels: Global, database,
>   table, column.

Answer (score 0):

what you do is check and update the required privilege in mysql.user table

```
update user set References_priv="Y" where user = 'your_user' ;
```